# How can i print only current user in HBS template

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js, passport.js

I want to print the currently logged in user, by getting the username from my database.

In my model, the username property holds the following schema:

```
{
  type: String, 
  required: true
}
```

**index.js:**

```
const users = require('../model/db');
router.get('/profiles/instructor', function (req, res, next) {
  users.find({}, 'username', (err, doc)=>{

    if(err){
      console.log('err while finding on instructor at index.js => ' + err)
    }else{
      console.log(doc)
      res.render('./profiles/instructor', { 
        title: 'Courstak | Instructor Profile',
        name: doc
// etc......
})
```

**ex.hbs:**

```
<h5>{{name}}</h5>
```

The issue that I am having is when I open my website, it shows all of the users within the database, not just the currently logged in user:

**Screenshot of error:**

[image]

Comment: It's hard to help with so much missing information. How do the users login? Where do you store session info? How is your app supposed to know which user it needs to display without some sort of login mechanism/session info? The short answer is; all users are displayed because you are querying for all users and not filtering in any fashion. `users.find({}, 'username', (err, doc)=>{` Running the following query returns every document, with only the username field: `users.find({}, 'username',`, and this passes all of that data to your template: `name: doc` That is why every user is shown.

Comment: Log in created with passport-local strategy

Comment: I false session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments of your OP that you're using the `passport-local` strategy, and it would appear that it very nicely connects up with `express` in the way you would expect, so `req.user` should have the information you are looking for, which would make your code like so [(assuming you're following the documentation to properly use `passport-local`)](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#configure-strategy):

```js
router.get('/profiles/instructor', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('./profiles/instructor', { 
        title: 'Courstak | Instructor Profile',
        name: req.user.username
    });
});
```

What I would recommend also is using some middleware such as `connect-ensure-login` to ensure that the user is logged in and has a valid session. You can add the middleware above like so:

```js
var connectEnsureLogin = require('connect-ensure-login')

router.get('/profiles/instructor',connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn(), function (req, res, next) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to add ```req.user``` but it is not working with any other action like ```'/'``` it just working with ```'/login'``` action that passport authenticated in it

Comment: It sounds like you may not be using passport.js correctly - have you [looked at an example such as this one](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js) and cross-referenced this with your code? You might very well be missing an `app.use(passport.session())` call, but I wouldn't know looking at the code you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much, this link helps me thank you i spent more that 10 hours misunderstanding why code doesn't work!!

Comment: If this answer has helped you, then you could consider marking this answer as accepted - see [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)